# sass: class name as a variable

Tags: javascript, sass, less

```
<ul>
  <li class="delay1">

  </li>
  <li class="delay2">

  </li>
  <li class="delay3">

  </li>
  <li class="delay4">

  </li>
  <li class="delay5">

  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  for (i=1;i<6;i++){
    $('li.delay'+i).css('transition-delay',100*i+'ms');
  }
</script>
```

How can I do the same thing with sass and WITHOUT javascript or having to write 5 lines of CSS?

I have read through the [learn sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide) page but I don't even know what this mechanic is called. It doesn't look like a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the for control directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10) along with [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .item-#{$i} { width: 2em * $i; }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the OP's classnames and styles, instead of copy+pasting the linked website?

Comment: Thanks, what I needed was actually the term "interpolation" so I can search. Yours is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    li.delay#{$i} {
        transition-delay: 100*$i;
    }
}
```